# JSON Formatting issue while decompression

Tags: java, json, gzip

I am getting the below JSON array after the decompression and it looks ugly with lots of extra `\\\\` appended and along with `\r` and `\n`. I need to convert this into java objects using gson. I am getting a parse error in that. Below is an excerpt from a huge JSON Array. Any good way to remove the unwanted slashes so that gson can parse it?

```
["\"{\\r\\n  \\\"MsgHdr\\\" : {\\r\\n    \\\"MsgFmtNr\\\" : \\\"CS00030538\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"MsgFmtVerNr\\\" : \\\"003.01\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"MsgInfSrcCd\\\" : \\\"XT\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"MsgOidNr\\\" : null,\\r\\n    \\\"MsgTs\\\" : \\\"2018-03-05 04:59:59\\\" }\\r\\n}\""]
```

Below are my compression and decompression methods. As huge volumes of jsons are pushed to Message queue(google pubsub), an extra zip effort is needed to compress.

```
public static byte[] compress(String data) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length());

    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);

    gzip.write(data.getBytes());

    gzip.close();

    byte[] compressed = bos.toByteArray();

    bos.close();

    return compressed;

}

public static String decompress(byte[] compressed) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);

        log.info("bytearrayinputstream is", bis);

        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bis);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));

        // StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line);

        }

        br.close();

        gis.close();

        bis.close();

    } catch (ZipException e) {
        log.info("Zip exception occured");
    }

    return sb.toString();


}
```

Comment: Are you manually doing gzip, no need to.. Browser will automatically handle gzip compression and decompression behind the scenes.. or please provide the code for gzip..

Comment: @numbtongue have added the compression and decompression code

Comment: Decompress logic assumes that the base64 encoded byte array was a UTF-8 encoded unicode character string.
So https://gist.github.com/yfnick/227e0c12957a329ad138#file-gzip-java-L14 should be data.getBytes("UTF-8");